# Слишком сложный SQL запросс

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, sqlite

У меня есть библиотека, в ней есть книги в оригинале (для каждой книги разный язык) и к ним (не ко всем) есть книги которые переведены на другие языки (вообще разные языки для каждой книги, к тому же их можеш бы разное количество для каждой книги), в базе храняться такие поля:

1. Идентификатор книги (для оригинала и переведенных книг по этому оригиналу одинаковые)
2. Названия книги
3. Язык на котором написана книга
4. Логическое поле - книга являеться оригиналом или нет

И пользователь запрашивает все доступные ему книги (предположим вообще все), у него стоит список из языков, последовательность которых нужно учитывать, к примеру, у него стоит:

1. Английский
2. Русский
3. Украинский

И ему нужно подать книгу (без разницы оригинал или перевод) на английском языке, если книги с таким переводом нет (либо это не оргинал) то на русском, если на русском нет (либо это не оригинал) то на украинском.

Comment: Не очень понятна фраза 'или если это не оригинал'. Из описанного алгоритма получается, что всегда нужно отдавать оригинал. Так же не понятен следующий момент. Вот есть запись с книгой с таким идентификатором и с таким названием на украинском языке. Как узнать - это язык оригинала иди нет?

Comment: @muturgan ну хорошо, нехватает колонки логического типа на проверку оригинала или нет, суть вопроса, всегда отдать человеку книги на наиболее подходящем языке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот запрос ещё нужно тестировать на данных.

```
SELECT book.name, book.is_origin, user_language_list.sort
FROM user_language_list
LEFT JOIN book
ON 
    user_language_list.user_id = ? 
    AND 
    book.id = ? 
    AND
    user_language_list.language_id = book.language_id
WHERE book.name IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY user_language_list.sort 
LIMIT 1
```

Идея в следующем (при условии, что пользователь один, а id книги заранее известно):

1. Берём список языков пользователя из таблицы user_language_list;
2. Присоединяем книги из таблицы book с нужным id;
3. Отсекаем строки, для которых нет книг в результирующем наборе (поле name - пусто);
4. Сортируем результирующий набор по приоритету из таблицы с языками пользователя;
5. Оставляем в выборке единственный результат.